# eigenspace of the power of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, general-linear-group

I know that if $Av=\lambda v$, $A^nv=\lambda^nv$, so powers of matrices inherit eigenvectors. But suppose $A$ is a square $d$ by $d$ matrix with $k<d$ eigenvectors; could $A^n$ have more eigenvectors for some $n$? Suppose $A$ is invertible, does that change anything?

I'm really just trying to find out if, for $A\in GL_d(\mathbb{C})$,  $A^n=I$ implies that $A$ has $d$ eigenvectors.

Comment: think of your matrix as already being in Jordan form. In raising the matrix to a power, the off-diagonal terms do not disappear.  So, yes, if $A^n=I$ then $A$ has a basis of eigenvectors, possibly requiring complex entries.

Comment: I think Will should enter his comment as an answer.  It is the answer!